# db2 sql giving me 0 as the result when divide operation is done

Tags: sql, math, db2, divide

```
SELECT CAST(64088.0200 AS DECIMAL(18,4))/ CAST(5555555555.0000 AS DECIMAL(18,4)) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

This Query is giving me 0 as the result but if you do it with normal calculator then its result is 0.0011535843601154 - So at least I need the result to be 0.0011

Please suggest on this.

Comment: I am on DB2 LUW 11.1 and it returns `0.0000115358436`. What version and platform are you on? A calculator also has `0.000011536..`.

Comment: i am on Power i (os 400 V7r2) and my result are : ,0000115358436 are you sur your result are not troncated by your client?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is simply maths

```
 db2 values 64088.02 / 5555555555

 1
 ---------------------------------
      0,00001153584360115358436011
```

So first of all you calculater result is wrong as the two comments prove as well.

```
db2 values cast(64088.02 / 5555555555 as decimal (18,4))

1
--------------------
              0,0000
```

The SQL result is 0 because you specified only 4 decimal places.

Extemding the decimal places will in the end show the correct result

```
db2 values cast(64088.02 / 5555555555 as decimal (18,8))

1
--------------------
          0,00001153
```

1 record(s) selected.